# Java JAX-RS @PUT annotation is not inherited

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, annotations, jax-rs

I have an abstract class which declares a `@PUT` method:

```
public abstract class BaseResource<T> {

  @PUT
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public abstract Response create(T entityClass);

}
```

Then a class implements the method:

```
public class GroupsResource extends BaseResource<Group> {

  @Override
  public Response create(Group newGroup) {

    // this works.
    // ...
    return response.build();

  }
}
```

Similar code with the GET method works, but this one is refused with a **405 Method Not Allowed**. But if I annotate the implementation with `@PUT` it does work. So it seems that the @PUT annotation on the abstract declaration is not being inherited.

Any thoughts?

UPDATE:

I have started from scratch with Java EE7 and this works great.

Comment: I just found a bug report that looks familiar, but while it is closed, it doesn't look like is fixed: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-636

Comment: In my opinion, I think you add more complexity if you use an abstract class.

Comment: Well, kind of. I like to abstract. And coherence is desirable too. By adding the method declarations on the abstract class, I *know* the behaviour of the classes that extend it even without reading.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my project and I resolved it like this:

```
//Inject the object mapper because you don't want to retreive an "Object"
@Inject
ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@PUT
//The PUT endpoint retrieves a plain object
public Response update(Object object){
   //Now we determine the concrete type of the object by using reflection
   ParameterizedType p = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
   Class<DTO> clazz = (Class<DTO>) p.getActualTypeArguments()[0];

   //Pass the object and the determined type to the objectmapper
   DTO dto = objectMapper.convertValue(object, clazz);

   //Now call an abstract method that deals with the object in you concrete class
   updateDto(dto);
}

protected abstract Response updateDto(DTO dto);
```